# Certificate Verify Failed Postgresql Heroku

Tags: python, asynchronous, heroku, heroku-postgres, asyncpg

I am running a PostgreSQL database through Heroku and asyncpg. My url is: `postgres://user:pass@ec2-23-21-76-49.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/db_name`.

When I run this, I get the error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)
```

This database url definitely works, it is valid when I use psycopg2. Just when I use asyncpg, I get this error.

I have tried not using a connection pool, that does not work either. Manually passing the user, password, etc. does not work either.

```
class Database:
    """Accessing database functions"""
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        try:
            self.dsn = os.environ["DATABASE_URL"]
        except KeyError:
            database_file = open('database_secret.txt', mode='r')
            self.dsn = database_file.read()
            database_file.close()

        self.pool = None
        self.prefix_conn = None
        self.prefix_stmt = None
        print(self.dsn)

        lop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        lop.run_until_complete(self.init())

    async def init(self):
        self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(self.dsn, ssl=True)
        # It fails here
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was probably because I had a new SSL certificate, and a really old version of the Heroku stack (cedar-14), really old python (2.7.9), and really old `requests` (2.5.1) module.

I upgrade everything (heroku-16 stack, python 2.7.14, `requests` 2.18.4), but probably the thing that resolved the issue was that `requests` now requires the `certifi` module. My understanding is that module handles the SSL validation now.